# UWP C# Disable Orientation Change Animation

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile

Is it possible to disable the 'screen rotating' animation that is executed when phone's rotation changes (from landscape to portrait or vice versa)?

Comment: Maybe this link will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19476025/wp8-orientation-change-animations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to use `DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences = DisplayOrientations.LandscapeFlipped | DisplayOrientations.Landscape;`

you need to set the orientation in OnNavigatedTo of  you pages, you can enable or disable different orientations depending of your pages or your requirements.

Update: If you want to rotate the buttons like the Camera app with a smooth animation there are some ways to do:

1.- Using Gyrometer :

You need to create your own animation with storyboards moving rotation of the buttons in realtime according of the position of the device. you will need to do some calculations to determine if the device is in portrait or landscape mode and move the buttons in realtime like Nokia Camera.

I did this approach for Windows Phone 8 it's very hard but the final work It was very good!
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br225718

2.- using OrientationChanged event

you need to listen the event OrientationChanged event and detest of the device is in portrait or landscape mode immediate you will need to execute some animations to your controls to be rotated you can do this approach using Blend and StoryBoards
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.display.displayproperties.orientationchanged.aspx

Here is an example to create a easy animation to rotate an image

https://comentsys.wordpress.com/2015/05/06/windows-10-universal-windows-platform-image-rotate/

The big difference between the two options is in the first option you offer a nice experience in real time changing the controls  depending of the orientation of the device with the second approach after the event is raised you will execute the animation.

Best regards

Please  mark this answer if it's useful for you!

Comment: I still want to support all orientations. I just don't want to have an animation when screen rotates between landscape to portrait or vice-versa.

Comment: I think is not possible

Comment: because this animation is handled by the OS

Comment: Thanks. Do you maybe know if is then possible to lock the orientation to let's say just Landscape (like you proposed in your original answer), but then somehow rotate just the soft navigation buttons (soft back, windows and search buttons) according to the rotation of the device?

I want to make the same kind of effect like the stock Windows 10 camera app has. When you rotate the screen, there is no rotation animation, but the navigation bar buttons rotate anyway.

Comment: I did something like that before I'll update my answer

Answer (score 4):

Go to package.appxmanifest
on Application tab
Supported rotations: Choose your Portrait or Landscape
[image]

Comment: That won't help a thing. Those are just *supported* rotations.

Comment: Worked for me. Rotating my device did not rotate the UI. Only supporting the portrait mode does disable rotation. (tested on lumia 930 with creator update and an app with min support for anniversary update 14933)