# Is it possible to lock orientation by device family in UWP app?

Tags: uwp, screen-orientation

I would like to lock screen orientation to portrait only for mobile family.
If I check only portrait in app manifest, it works: screen is locked in portrait orientation for mobile, but I think it is the same for tablets (Actually, I haven't tablet device for testing).

Comment: *"Actually, I haven't tablet device for testing"* - But you do have a PC for testing, right?

Comment: Yes I have a PC but I believe there isn't orientation restriction on PC because I can display the app window as I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this SO answer 
[UWP C# Disable Orientation Change Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35663676/uwp-c-sharp-disable-orientation-change-animation)

You need to set your screen orientation in your `OnNavigatedTo` override.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
      if(/*on phone*/)
      {
        DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences = DisplayOrientation.//Your Enum Value
      }
}
```

Here is a list of the [DisplayOrientations off of the MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br226142)

[image]