# Rotate soft on screen buttons on windows phone UWP

Tags: c#, button, uwp, screen-orientation, device-orientation

Does anyone know how to rotate soft on screen buttons when orientation changes in C#, windows phone 10?

I wish to keep display orientation to be portrait or landscape to avoid animation when display orientation changes. I can rotate all content buttons on DeviceOrientation.OrientationChanged event, but I don't know if there is a way to access and rotate on screen buttons.

I have found severan answers that are marked as answered like this one:
[UWP C# Disable Orientation Change Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35663676/uwp-c-sharp-disable-orientation-change-animation/35664965)
but they all talk about how to detect if orientation is changed. I can't find any example of how to rotate soft on screen buttons.

The effect should be like on windows phone native camera.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the orientation sensor to get your device`s orientation ,and then set angel of your **Button.Projection**

Reference Links:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/use-the-orientation-sensor

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private SimpleOrientationSensor simpleorientation;
    private double? Current = 0;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        simpleorientation = SimpleOrientationSensor.GetDefault();
        if (simpleorientation != null)
        {
            simpleorientation.OrientationChanged += new TypedEventHandler<SimpleOrientationSensor, SimpleOrientationSensorOrientationChangedEventArgs>(OrientationChanged);
        }
    }

    private async void OrientationChanged(SimpleOrientationSensor sender, SimpleOrientationSensorOrientationChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            SimpleOrientation orientation = args.Orientation;
            switch (orientation)
            {
                case SimpleOrientation.NotRotated:
                    Rotate(0);
                    break;

                case SimpleOrientation.Rotated90DegreesCounterclockwise:
                    Rotate(90);
                    break;

                case SimpleOrientation.Rotated180DegreesCounterclockwise:
                    Rotate(180);
                    break;

                case SimpleOrientation.Rotated270DegreesCounterclockwise:
                    Rotate(270);
                    break;

                case SimpleOrientation.Faceup:
                    break;

                case SimpleOrientation.Facedown:
                    break;

                default:

                    break;
            }
        });
    }

    private void Rotate(double value)
    {
        MyAnimation.From = Current;
        MyAnimation.To = (360 - value);
        myStoryBoard.Begin();
        Current = MyAnimation.To;
    }
}
```

XAML code:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Button
        x:Name="TestButton"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Content="button">
        <Button.Projection>
            <PlaneProjection x:Name="Projection" RotationZ="0" />
        </Button.Projection>
    </Button>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="myStoryBoard">
            <DoubleAnimation
                x:Name="MyAnimation"
                Storyboard.TargetName="Projection"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="RotationZ"
                Duration="0:0:1" />
        </Storyboard>
    </Grid.Resources>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Doesn't this just animate buttons that I put on screen in grid? I am interested in how to rotate hardware on screen buttons.